# SQL Query only retrieving one row

Tags: php, sql, database, web

I have a a php website with some code on it to pull from a database after the user has defined some search terms and then show them a table with all their information in it

The problem is even when i do a select * from the tables, i am only getting the first row back.

Code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT trees.*     
FROM trees 
INNER JOIN price 
ON trees.ID=price.treeid  
");


$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows == 0) {
echo "No rows retrieved";
} else {
echo $num_rows;
}
```

i have 2 rows in my database:

```
Spruce  El Sorbeous Sprucious   Green   Green   Green   100     200
its a tree ma!  true    NULL    NULL    NULL

Mayday  el daymay   red green   white   10  4000000
GOING DOWN  true    Grey    true    false
```

when i print out the $num_rows up there, it is only one.
When i print out my table below, there is only one row:

```
echo '<table border = 0 cellpadding=0 >';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b><u>Name</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Latin Name</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Primary Color</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Secondary Color</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Fall Color</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Trunk Color</b></u></td>';

echo '<td><b><u>Description</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Height</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Spread</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Drought Resistant?</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Flowering?</b></u></td>
<td><b><u>Fruit Producing?</b></u></td>';

echo '</tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['name'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['latinname'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['primarycolor'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['secondarycolor'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['fallcolor'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['trunkcolor'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['description'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['height'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['spread'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['droughtresistant'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['flowering'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '<td>';
     echo $row['fruitproducing'];
     echo '</td>';

     echo '</tr>';

}
echo '<table>';
```

Comment: the 2nd code block is the database data.  but i did just notice i put the reference key into the price table instead of the tree table.  i had my foreign keys backwards! this may or may not fix my problem?

Comment: who knew it was irrelevant to the question before the question was asked? not me .

other people seemed to find interesting problems in my setup, while you just complained.  the other answers got me my answer.

Comment: Well i will edit it and put the answer up when i have some time.  The problem was faily hard to document here as my table structure was wrong, and reading the peoples responses made me check the structure for proper foreign key contraints, which i was missing, which when implemented, fixed my problem.  So i am unaware of how to properly document this situation.

Comment: no point in faking the question, as you suggested.  The initial question stands, and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no example of the data in the PRICE table, I'm guessing that only one row was joined.

The question remains, why are you doing that JOIN? You're not collecting any data from the PRICE table, so what's the point.
BTW, where in the data is the ID?

Comment: you are right, and perhaps i should have added more code, i jsut didnt want to overwhelm anyone.

Table a has rows that reference rows in table b (price)

multiple rows from table a could reference the same row in table b.

So evetually i need to display all the data from both tables in a html table.

Comment: Chose this as the correct answer because i was missing my ID foreign key constraint, and this poster made me think of it and check my DB structure again

Answer (score 3):

INNER JOIN will only return values that have NOT NULL values in both tables. You are probably joining stuff with a NULL value. Use a LEFT or a RIGHT join instead!

Comment: i removed the join, and i got both rows.

Now say multiple rows in table a are references 1 row in table b, and i want to display all the rows, with the duplicated data from table b, how can i do that?

I thought a join would copy the data from table b for each row in table a that references it?

Comment: @jordan.peoples if the information exists in the trees table and you are joining another table with MIGHT have more info, use a LEFT JOIN. Same as before but with the word LEFT instead of the word INNER